# how to write parameter string for include for linq query?

Tags: linq

If table Employee has foreign key for table person, department, 
when get the entity of employee, I want to both associated entities loaded too. 
how to write the linq query? like below?

```
var employee = this.Context.Employee.Include("Person, Department");
```

It seems not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var employee = this.Context.Employee.Include("Person").Include("Department");
```